# How to scale to be at the same distance in all devices?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scale

I'm having problems opening my game in different divices , in the 6s iphone plus looks much bigger the circle the center, also the small circle that is on the line changes position , I would like that the center circle was the same size and that the small circle always this half on the line.

```
import SpriteKit


struct Circle {
var position:CGPoint
var radius:CGFloat
}

 class GameScene: SKScene {
 let node = SKNode()
let sprite = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 6)
 var rotation:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)
var circles:[Circle] = []
 var circuloFondo = SKSpriteNode()
 var orbita = SKSpriteNode()

let padding2:CGFloat =  26.0
let padding3:CGFloat =  33.5

let padding5:CGFloat =  285.5
var circulo = SKSpriteNode()
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
scaleMode = .ResizeFill

    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.65, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1)

orbita = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "orbita2")
orbita.size = CGSize(width:view.frame.size.width - padding2 , height: view.frame.size.width - padding2)
orbita.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
orbita.colorBlendFactor = 1
orbita.alpha = 1
orbita.position = view.center
self.addChild(orbita)
orbita.zPosition = 3


circuloFondo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circuloFondo")
circuloFondo.size = CGSize(width:view.frame.size.width - padding5 ,  height: view.frame.size.width - padding5)
circuloFondo.color = UIColor.whiteColor()
circuloFondo.alpha = 1
circuloFondo.position = view.center
self.addChild(circuloFondo)
circuloFondo.zPosition = 0

    let radius1:CGFloat = (view.frame.size.width - padding3)/2 - 1
    let radius2:CGFloat = (view.frame.size.width - padding5)/2 + 6.5

circles.append(Circle(position: view.center, radius: radius1))
circles.append(Circle(position: view.center, radius: radius2))
addChild(node)


node.addChild(sprite)
if let circle = nextCircle() {
node.position = circle.position
sprite.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
sprite.zPosition = 4.0
sprite.position = CGPoint(x:circle.radius, y:0)
rotate()
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please make your question clear, it is quite confusing..

Comment: I recommend you check my answer to avoid causing yourself tons of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the width of the screen like this:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
```

and then set elements in your UI to be a proportion of the screenWidth.  For instance:

```
let radius1:CGFloat = screenWidth/4
//this would always give you a radius that is one quarter of the screen width
```

I've used this method a few times with success, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is your scene mode is set to ResizeFill. This will cause you so many headaches as you will have to do all the scaling yourself, hence the circles are different sizes on different devices. Having scale mode resizeFill will also affect things such as the physics engine or fontSizes which you will need to adjust for on every device.

I would recommend you use scene scale mode .AspectFill with the default scene size of 1024*768 (landscape) or 768*1024 (portrait). This is the same as the xCode default game template.

This way everything will look exactly the same on all iPhones. On iPads there will be slightly more screen space at the top and bottom which you simply cover with your background. The main trick is that you position your stuff from the center.

Furthermore you can use the universal assets in the asset catalogue and everything will look great and not blurry.

The only thing that you might have to adjust for this way is that on iPads you might need to move some buttons up/down if you want them on the top/bottom edge.

I strongly recommend you consider this as I can talk from experience that using scale mode ResizeFill is really bad. I have been  through this pain with 2 games before I rewrote them because they were so inconsistent on all devices causing me so many bugs in the process. Lets not talk about the time I wasted testing on all devices, adjusting values until it felt right.

Hope this helps.